# Jboss Not starting in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, jboss

i am trying to run jboss v6 in netbeans but it shows following error

```
Unable to read the logging configuration from 'file:logging.properties' (java.io.FileNotFoundException: logging.properties (The system cannot find the file specified))
```

If i run jboss stnadalone by directly going in bin/run.bat no error is displaying and it starts normally but in netbeans i am getting error as i mentioned above.

Can Anyone tell me what to do for solving this problem?

Comment: I doubt that that is an error , start jb from nb and then try hitting http://localhost:8080 and see what do you get

Comment: but this is slowing my netbeasns .will you tell me what should i do

Comment: slowing is a diff issue , which mainly has to do with the RAM you have on your system , also try not to open all applications at once , as that will slow down processing

Comment: Jboss is keep processing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You copied the JDK out from "Program Files" and placed in C:\, and then configured JBOSS's run.conf from bin folder to point to the new location of JDK. For example

```
   rem set "JAVA_HOME=C:\jdk1.6.0_13"
```

Comment: where logging.properties is located ?

Answer (score 6):

I found this answer somewhere else on the web:

> Go to the “bin” directory where you’ve installed JBoss
> Edit the “run.bat” file
>
> Search for the line
>
> `set JAVA_OPTS=-Dprogram.name=%PROGNAME% -Dlogging.configuration=file:%DIRNAME%logging.properties %JAVA_OPTS%`
>
> Change the %DIRNAME% to your absolute path to the “bin” directory of your installed JBoss.e.g.
>
> `set JAVA_OPTS=-Dprogram.name=%PROGNAME% -Dlogging.configuration=file:"C:\Java\jboss-6.1.0-final\bin\logging.properties" %JAVA_OPTS%`
>
> I’m adding the double quote " so that if your directory name has spaces, it will still be legitimate.
>
> Try to start your server through Netbeans again, it should be working fine after this.

Edit: [One likely source](http://www.developerscrappad.com/759/java/java-ee/jboss/quick-fix-how-to-solve-unable-to-read-the-logging-configuration-on-netbeans7-with-jboss6/)

Comment: Instead of doing the above, you can as well look for the line 'set DIRNAME=' and then comment it out as follows:

rem set DIRNAME=